# How to understand errors(combined) at Google Spanner Monitor?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

Google Spanner monitor provides helpful information about databases and instance. Operation per seconds view contains **errors(combined)** measure that is not clear for me.

[image: Spanner monitor]

How to understand **errors(combined)**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a dashboard in Stackdriver (https://app.google.stackdriver.com) that will break down the errors slightly. We're working on a resources page for Cloud Spanner right now that will actually break them down by error code, but before that, you can go to Resources > Metrics Explorer and filter by response status:
[image: view of Stackdriver metrics explorer]

You'll occasionally get error responses using the Cloud Spanner API; FAILED_PRECONDITION is somewhat common if you have a lot of transactions happening simultaneously that invalidate other transactions.